# Facing difficulties in fusion chart to display records using msstackedcolumn2d

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm working on angular fusion chart with `Multi Series Stacked Column 2d` chart using `Angularjs`. I'm facing *3 issues* in my *fusion chart* those are mentioned below:

- I'm not able to *find the bars in my fusion chart* if i pass only one data
- I get the *bars in the fusion chart* if i send *more than one data*, but few data shows `zero` value in it.
- When i *click on the generate button* again for the same search it shows me `zero` records in it *even if there is a records*.

Let me show you the `script` and the `html` that I'm using for *fusion chart*.

**Index.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid mid-content" ng-show='searchResults'>
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-1" id="outPopUp">
          <div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" chart="{{attrs}}"
                    categories="{{categories}}"
                    dataset="{{dataset}}">
           </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**json data**

```
[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
```

**script.js**

```
$scope.categories = [{
    "font": "Arial",
    "fontsize": "15",
    "fontcolor": "000000"

  }];
  $scope.attrs = {
    "palette": "3",
    "numdivlines": '3',
    "numberprefix": "",
    "useRoundEdges": "1",
    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
    "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "yaxismaxvalue": "10000",
    "showLegend": "1",
    "showborder": "0",
    "labelDisplay": "wrap",
    "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
    "maxLabelHeight": "1500"
  };


    $scope.dataset = [];
  $scope.generate = function() {
  $scope.searchResults = false
  $scope.showLoader = true
  var data = reportService.allocationCollection($scope.query).success(function(data) {

    var products = [];
    var buckets = [];
    var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};

    var seriesItem = {};
    var catHolder = {};
    var valHolder = {};
    var valCollection = [];
    var allocatedCollection = [];
    var collectedCollection = [];
    var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];

    var tempDataSet = {};
    var maxYaxisVal = 0;

      $scope.dataset2 = data

      for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {

        if (data[i].allocatedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        }
        if (data[i].collectedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].collectedAccount;
        }
        if (products.indexOf(data[i].product) == -1) {
          item = {};
          item["label"] = "Allocated\t\tCollected(" + data[i].product +")";
          item["font"] = "Arial";
          item["fontsize"] = "15";

          catObject.push(item);
          products.push(data[i].product);
        }
        if ((i == (data.length - 1))) {
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
          allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
          collectedCollection.push(valHolder);
        }
        if ((buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket) == -1) || (i == (data.length - 1))) {               

          if (buckets.length > 0) {
            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i - 1].bucket + "allocated";
            seriesItem["data"] = allocatedCollection;
            allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);

            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i - 1].bucket + "collected";

            seriesItem["data"] = collectedCollection;
            collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
            collectedCollection = [];
            allocatedCollection = [];
            console.log(allocatedDataSet)
          }
          buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
          console.log(buckets.length);
        }
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
        collectedCollection.push(valHolder);


      }
      catHolder["category"] = catObject;
      catCollection.push(catHolder);


      tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;
      dataSet = [];
      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      tempDataSet = {};
      tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      $scope.categories = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
      $scope.attrs.yaxismaxvalue = maxYaxisVal;


    $scope.showLoader = false;
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 'slow');
    }, 200);

    $scope.results = data;


    if ($scope.results.length > 0) {
      console.log($scope.query.product);

      $scope.searchResults = true
        //console.log("hi");
      _.forEach($scope.results.entities, function(obj) {
        console.log("hi");
        obj.isChecked = false;
      });
      console.log("hi1");
      $scope.view_data = $scope.results.slice($scope.skip, $scope.items + $scope.skip);
      //console.log("hi2");
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.results.length;
      console.log(data);

      $scope.results = data;
      //$scope.results = $filter('orderByValue')(data);
      // called on header click





    } else {
      $scope.searchResults = false
      notificationFactory.warning('No results Found')
      $scope.showLoader = false
    }



  }).error(function(data) {
    notificationFactory.warning('Error Searching Reports')
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Please can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong. Because I'm new to this *fusion chart*.

Comment: It would be very helpful if  you could re-produce the issue in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @ pritishvaidya i have some Api data in it can i  share my  working folder to  you.

Comment: Just the basic functionality where it is throwing the error,you can replace the data with the dummy data and reproduce the fiddle

Comment: @  pritishvaidya  k  , give me a minute

Comment: @ pritishvaidya here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u7ju71oo/8/

Comment: @ pritishvaidya sorry forgot  to  add  the json  data to  it.

Comment: @ pritishvaidya  i have posted the json  data also

Comment: @ pritishvaidya any  update found ?

Comment: the problem statement in your question states that you are not able to get the bars for one data,but i cannot see any bars generated.So it would take me some time to reproduce the complete issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.chartoptions = {
    "dataEmptyMessage": "No data to display <br> Do these steps..."
  };
  data =[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 153,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
$scope.attrs = {
                "palette":"3",
                "numdivlines":'3',
                "numberprefix": "",
                "useRoundEdges":"1",
                "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
                "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "yaxismaxvalue": "1000",
                "showLegend":"1",
                "showborder": "0",
                "labelDisplay": "wrap", 
                "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
                "maxLabelHeight":"150"
             };
var products = [];
var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};
     var catHolder = {};
      var buckets = [];
      var dataSet=[];
       var seriesItem = {};
       var productWiseAllocationarr=[];
       var productWiseCollectionarr= [];
        var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];
      var tempDataSet = {};
      var allseries={};
      var collseries={};
      var allocatedData = [];
    var collectedData = [];

     for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (products.indexOf(data[i].product)== -1)
                {
                    item = {};
                    item["label"] = "Allocated\tCollected   " + data[i].product;
                    item["font"] = "Arial";
                    item["fontsize"] = "15";

                    catObject.push(item);
                    products.push(data[i].product);
                    catHolder["category"] =  catObject ;

                }
                 if (buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket)==-1)
                {

                         buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
                }


     }
     for(var j=0;j<products.length;j++)
     {
     for(var p=0;p<data.length;p++)
     {
     if(data[p].product==products[j])
     {
     var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].allocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].collectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);
     }
     }
     }
     for(var b =0;b<buckets.length;b++)
     {
      allseries = {};
       allseries.name =buckets[b]+"allocated";
       allseries.data=[];
        collseries = {};
       collseries.name =buckets[b]+"collected";
       collseries.data=[];
     for(var pr=0;pr< productWiseAllocationarr.length;pr++)
     {
       if(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {

       allseries.data.push(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].amount);


       }
        if( productWiseCollectionarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {

       collseries.data.push(productWiseCollectionarr[pr].amount);


       }
     }
      allocatedData.push(allseries);
       collectedData.push(collseries);
     }
    for(var w=0;w<allocatedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] = allocatedData[w].name;
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<allocatedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=allocatedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
        allocatedData[w].data;
        allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }

         for(var w=0;w< collectedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] =  collectedData[w].name;

        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<collectedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=collectedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
         collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
     tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;


            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet = {};
            tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
   catCollection.push(catHolder);

      $scope.categories  = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic was not correctly implemented for Multi-series stacked column chart. The resultant JSON structure of the code does not comply to the supported format for the said chart hence data was getting wrongly visualized for both the categories.

Please visit the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Akash008/u7ju71oo/39/

Please check the modified script

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.chartoptions = {
    "dataEmptyMessage": "No data to display <br> Do these steps..."
  };
  data =[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
$scope.attrs = {
                "palette":"3",
                "numdivlines":'3',
                "numberprefix": "",
                "useRoundEdges":"1",
                "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
                "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "yaxismaxvalue": "1000",
                "showLegend":"1",
                "showborder": "0",
                "labelDisplay": "wrap", 
                "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
                "maxLabelHeight":"150"
             };
var products = [];
var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};
     var catHolder = {};
      var buckets = [];
      var dataSet=[];
       var seriesItem = {};
       var productWiseAllocationarr=[];
       var productWiseCollectionarr= [];
        var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];
      var tempDataSet = {};
      var allseries={};
      var collseries={};
      var allocatedData = [];
    var collectedData = [];
     
     for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (products.indexOf(data[i].product)== -1)
                {
                    item = {};
                    item["label"] = "Allocated\tCollected   " + data[i].product;
                    item["font"] = "Arial";
                    item["fontsize"] = "15";
           
                    catObject.push(item);
                    products.push(data[i].product);
                    catHolder["category"] =  catObject ;
            
                }
                 if (buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket)==-1)
                {
                
                         buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
                }
               
            
     }
     for(var j=0;j<products.length;j++)
     {
     for(var p=0;p<data.length;p++)
     {
     if(data[p].product==products[j])
     {
     var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].allocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].collectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);
     }
     }
     }
     for(var b =0;b<buckets.length;b++)
     {
      allseries = {};
       allseries.name =buckets[b]+"allocated";
       allseries.data=[];
        collseries = {};
       collseries.name =buckets[b]+"collected";
       collseries.data=[];
     for(var pr=0;pr< productWiseAllocationarr.length;pr++)
     {
       if(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {
      
       allseries.data.push(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].amount);
       
        
       }
        if( productWiseCollectionarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {
       
       collseries.data.push(productWiseCollectionarr[pr].amount);
      
        
       }
     }
      allocatedData.push(allseries);
       collectedData.push(collseries);
     }
    for(var w=0;w<allocatedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] = allocatedData[w].name;
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<allocatedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=allocatedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
        allocatedData[w].data;
        allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
       
         for(var w=0;w< collectedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] =  collectedData[w].name;
        
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<collectedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=collectedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
         collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
     tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;

           
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet = {};
            tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
   catCollection.push(catHolder);
     
      $scope.categories  = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
        });
```

```html
<html ng-app="HelloApp">

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
         <div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" dataSource="{{dataSource}}" categories="{{categories}}" chart="{{attrs}}" dataFormat= 'json' dataset="{{dataset}}" events="events">
                          </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```